# Auth0 securing API for public endpoint

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, auth0

I have web app developed using .net core and react front end. I am currently using Auth0 platform to secure APIs and some of the APIs need public access, how can I achieve the security of the public APIs using the Auth0 platform ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also setup third party application in Auth0, then let those applications have whatever access you deem fit through the dashboard. This can be done programmatically via the management api if you are going to let users register their own applications via your own UI.

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/user-consent

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at using an api gateway to secure your APIs. AWS offers a service called Api Gateway that allows you to perform custom authorization on requests made to your endpoints before they're sent to your backend. So you could set up a custom authorizer to talk to Auth0 and filter requests that way.

[This article](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway/custom-authorizers) might be a good place to start researching this.